# PowerPoint 2013 only presenter view

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

i try to show only  the presenter view (with speaker notes) and to hide the presentation view. I have read, that this would work (with only one monitor) by pressing ALT+F5, but if i have more than one it will always shows the presentation view.

Is there an option or macro-fuction that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have two monitors connected, and view presenter view on only one screen, with neither the regular presentation view, or the presenter view on the other screen, try this:

1. Run the presentation with presenter view on.
2. Left click on the regular presentation view on the secondary screen
3. Press and hold down both the shift key and the Windows key, then press the right or left arrow key once.
4. The regular presentation view should now be on top of the presenter view with notes
5. Click the presenter view to bring it to the front, hiding the regular presentation view behind it.

This uses the window snap feature, normally used to tile a window to the right or left half of your screen (Windows key + left or right arrow key), but with the shift key modifier to make it move the window from one display to another.